# Why am I not gettiing anything when I click the submit button?

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

This is the html code..

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button").click(function(){
            var senda=$("#ans").val();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"ajax.php",
                data:{"answer":"senda"},
                dataType:"json",
                success: function()(msg,string,jqXHR){
                    $("#result").html(msg+string+jqXHR);
                }
            });
        });
    });



</script>
</head>
<body>
Hey what has a head and a tail but no body?
<input type="text" id="ans" name="ans" />
<input type="button" id="button" value="submit" />
<p><div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the code of the php file ajax.php:-

```
<?php 

$y=$_REQUEST['answer'];
echo "hey $y ";
if($y=='coin'){
    echo "hey it worked";
}

?>
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong.The html code runs fine initially but when I click the submit button nothing happens. I now this might be just very beginner kinda question,actually I am just learning Jquery and php. What I am actually trying to do is take an input from the user and check if the input matches a string and then take the user to a new page.So any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have many syntax errors in your code. Please take a look at [jQuery.ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: `data:{"answer":senda},` . I am astonished that you din't get any error in your browser cosole ,or you didn't checked  yet?  Also `=` need to convert into `:` i n your ajax code

Comment: @Anant That's not his only issue, `type="POST"`, `url="ajax.php",`, `success: function()(msg,string,jqXHR){` these are all wrong!

Comment: What I am actually trying to do is take an input from the user and check if the input matches a string and then take the user to a new page. Actually I recently learnt how to do the checking in chrome..thanks for pointing it all out...I have corrected most of the stuff but I am not sure about the "success" part.

Comment: can u please tell me what changes should i make to the success part...i changed other = s to : @Anant

Comment: Also not returning json as requested from server. Don't request json if you want html or text. Study some ajax tutorials and the `documentation

Comment: Please update your post and include the corrected version of your code. for the success part, first of all its recommended to use `.done()` instead, but your current code should be `success: function(msg,string,jqXHR){` you have an extra `()` in your code

Comment: and you are sending one property but looking for a different one in server code  `'answer' != 'ans'`. For very basic starters learn to use browser console to check for errors

Comment: hey charlie actually what I am trying to do is I want to take the users input from the input portion and then check if it equals a specific string ..if it does i want to move to the new page automatically ...pls tell me what changes can be made ..

Comment: and also you have to enclose your strings in your object in quotes, so it should be like `data:{"answer": "senda"},`

Comment: if you have a property named `answer` in your ajax data object, then you have to have `$y=$_REQUEST['answer'];` or better to have `$y=$_POST['answer'];` on your php file

Comment: and again, since in your code you are using `jquery 3.1.1` and according to [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): _Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead_. So you have to use `.done()` instead of `.success()`

Comment: thanks for the info ehsaan

Comment: :) you are welcome...

Comment: One thing, I did not see that `senda` is a variable, so you do not need to enclose it in quotes it should be like this: `data:{"answer": senda},`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. fix your ajax data:

   ```
       var senda=$("#ans").val();
       $.ajax({
           type:"POST",
           url:"ajax.php",
           data:{"answer":senda} // without quotes
       }).done(function(response) {
           $("#result").html(response);
       });
   ```
2. handle passed data using param name:

   ```
   $y = $_POST['answer'];
   echo "hey $y ";
   if ($y == 'coin') {
       echo "hey it worked";
   }
   ```

Comment: You forgot to fix the `success` part ;)

Comment: Also since the response is only a text, so the `dataType` can not be `json` and it should be `dataType:"text",`

Comment: `dataType:"json"` means that passed data have JSON format, it is not connected with response

Comment: No, `datatype` means that the you will tell your ajax call to expect what type of data in response! This is from the [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)  _The type of data that you're expecting back from the server._

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134273/discussion-between-taron-saribekyan-and-ehsant).

Comment: k thanks a lot to both of you  for all the details ...but now i am geting this error in my console....

jquery.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/spyder/try/ajax.php. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
send @ jquery.min.js:4

Comment: owkkh thank god..it finally workd ....used localhost instead of loading file directly.... :)

Comment: It means you run your code out of server. Is your URL something like this: 
`file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/spyder/try/FILE_NAME.html` ?